A connection on a complex vector bundle whose group is $SU(n)$
Let $E\to M$ be a smooth complex vector bundle, and $D:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)=\Omega^1(E)$ be a connection on $E$, which is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map satisfying $D(fs)=fDs+df\otimes s$ for $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $s\in \Gamma(E)$. In p.33 of the book Instantons and Four-Manifolds by Freed and Uhlenbeck, it is written that: Suppose $E$ has a metric. If the group of the bundle is $SU(n)$, then for orthonormal local sections $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ we require that $D(\sigma_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \sigma_n)=0$.
What does this condition mean? I see that $\sigma_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \sigma_n$ is a section of $E^{\otimes n}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form#Wedge_product) and that $D$ induces a connection (which we also denote by $D$) on $E^{\otimes n}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Tensor_product_connection), so that $D(\sigma_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \sigma_n)$ is defined. But I don't see why do we require this.

Perhaps that alternating $n$-tensor is related to the $\det = 1$ condition.

It is important to realize that $\sigma_1\wedge\dots\wedge\sigma_n$ is not only a section of the bundle $E^{\ootimes^n}$ but even of the line bundle $\Lambda^nE$ (so the condition that this is parallel becomes much weaker).
